# Can't run javascript after redirecting to another page in cordova app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ratchet

I have a problem that's been troubling me for days.
In short i have index.html page that displays first a login page for the user when the app starts. In there i load my file scripts.js which cotains functions for all of the pages (including signup.html), but the problem is there is a function showTab() that has to run when the user wants to create account and gets redirected to the signup.html page
I do that like this:

```
<a class="text-info font-weight-bold h5 text-underline"  href="signup.html" data-transition="slide-in"><U>Create
one now!</U></a>
```

So you can see where the problem is when the app actually loads the scrips.js is loaded and the function showTab() which should run on signup.html passes once on the index page and when the user tried to go to signup.html with the href and data-transition="slide-in" the scripts.js is not loaded all over to re-run the function showTab() which is first line in scripts.js
One way to solve this is to change data-transition="slide-in" to data-ignore="push" which causes the signup.html to reload actually but that loses the transition.
I use Ratchet framework and Cordova to build the app ultimately. 
I tried also adding onload="showTab()" in signup.html

```
<div class="content bg-primary" onload="showTab()>
```

Which again doesn't reload the JS.

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** try to navigate between pages with Cordova.

This is the first item from the [Best Practices Cordova app development](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/index.html#best-practices-cordova-app-development):

> First and foremost - your Cordova applications should adopt the SPA
>   (Single Page Application) design. Loosely defined, a SPA is a
>   client-side application that is run from one request of a web page.
>   The user loads an initial set of resources (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript)
>   and further updates (showing a new view, loading data) is done via
>   AJAX. SPAs are commonly used for more complex client-side
>   applications. GMail is a great example of this. After you load GMail,
>   mail views, editing, and organization are all done by updating the DOM
>   instead of actually leaving the current page to load a completely new
>   one.

Pay special attention to this:

> Even if you choose not to use Cordova, creating a mobile application
>   without using a single page architecture will have serious performance
>   implications. This is because navigating between pages will require
>   scripts, assets, etc., to be reloaded. Even if these assets are
>   cached, there will still be performance issues.